# For random variables $Y,Z,X,W$, how to show $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X,W]|X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X,W]|Z,X]|X]$?

Tags: probability

I am wondering how to use the properties of conditional expectations to show that:

$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X,W]|X] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X,W]|Z,X]|X]
$$

for random variables $Y,Z,X,W$? It appears to me that this may not hold generally but I am having trouble proving otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the law of iterated expectations
$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X,W]|X] = \mathbb{E}[Y|X]$$

$$\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X,W]|Z,X]|X]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|Z,X]|X]=\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$$

Answer (score 3):

Both sides are equal to $E(Y|X)$. All you have to do is to use repeatedly the property $E(E(Y|\{X_i\}|\{Z_j\})=E(E(Y|\{Z_j\})$ whenever $\{Z_j\}$ is a subcollection of $\{X_i\}$. If you aer familiar with the general definition of conditional expectations what you need is the property $E(E(Y|\mathcal G_1)|\mathcal G_2)=E(Y|\mathcal G_2)$ if $\mathcal G_2 \subset \mathcal G_1$.

Answer (score 1):

If F is a subalgebra of G, then E[E[X|F]|G]=E[E[X|G]|F]=E[X|F].

First, E[E[X|F]|G]=E[X|F] because E[X|F] is G-measurable.

To prove that E[E[X|G]|F]=E[X|F], for all F-measurable event A, E[E[E[X|G]|F]1_A]=E[E[E[X|G]1_A|F]]=E[E[X|G]1_A]=E[E[X1_A|G]]=E[X1_A].

since E[E[X|G]|F] is F-measurable, it is equal to E[X|F] a.s. by the definition of conditional expectation.

All you have to do is to apply this result to your example.